# PHP Fatal Error: Call to undefined method even though the method exists in the Main Class

Tags: php

I am using PHP and am accessing my Main Class but it shows this error "

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method MainClass::filterUser() in
>   C:\Users\ianga_000\Desktop\asd -
>   Copy\root\MerckThesis\ForgotPassword.php on line 18"

The filterUser method is inside my Main Class.

This is my php code

```
<form action="ForgotPassword.php" method="POST">    

    User Name:<input type="text" name="txtUserName" value="" ?/><br/>
    <?php
    include_once("MainClass.php");

    $MainClass = new MainClass;

    if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]))
    {
        $username=$_POST['txtUserName'];

        $MainClass -> filterUser($username);

        session_start();

        $MainClass -> mailForgotPassword($_SESSION['email'],$_SESSION['password']);
    }
    ?>

    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

and this is the code in my Main Class

```
<?php 


class MainClass
{

    function filterUser($username)
    {
        require 'Connection.php';
        $strSQL="SELECT * FROM users where userName='$username'";


        $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
        $result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

        if($result)
        {
            $_SESSION['email']=$result["email"];
            $_SESSION['password']=$result['password'];
        }

        mysql_close($con);

    }

}



?>
```

EDIT: It just happens that my MainClass is so messed up and the function was outside of the main class

Comment: why spaces between method reference by class `$MainClass -> filterUser` should be like `$MainClass->filterUser`

Comment: Remove spaces and try.

Comment: and use mysqli... mysql is dead

Comment: @Noman i did remove the spaces but the error is still there

Comment: @Noman that has nothing to do with the question. Both are valid php...

Comment: you should post your class along. also try (`var_dump($MainClass);`)

Comment: please try with public function filterUser($username).

Comment: sidenote: you might want to start the session before stuffing data in `$_SESSION`

Comment: Provide the whole MainClass or at least a bit more than just an inner method. Also I'm not sure if when you declare a method by just saying `function` it automatically appears as public. I believe you should specify explicitly that this method is public.

Comment: Are you sure that mainclass.php is loaded? Try using require_once which will trigger an error.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud do what? o_O

Comment: none of those worked guys :(

Comment: @YellowSubmarine make sure that function is *indeed* inside the class and not just inside the file (after the closing `}` of the class) . Can you make a pastebin link?

Comment: @emil.c my Main Class is 2086 lines long :/ and I did try explicitly declaring my function as public but it didn't work too

Comment: So just provide the beginning and end of your class and the method. The point is to see how you actually declare the method inside the class. Also providing your constructor would be good idea as well.

Comment: Make your method public or try adding `()` after new `MainClass`.

Comment: @Ali `()` are not necessary if there are no arguments passed. However if your MainClass is so long, I think it diserves splitting.

Comment: Can you please show the full code of your ForgotPassword.php file?

Comment: @Ali that is the whole content of my ForgotPassword.php file

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, your class code should look like follows (as for sure you have to replace mysql methods with mysqli or PDO):

```
class MainClass {

    public function filterUser($username)
    {
        require 'Connection.php';
        $strSQL="SELECT * FROM users where userName='$username'";

        $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($rs);

        if($result)
        {
            $_SESSION['email']=$result["email"];
            $_SESSION['password']=$result['password'];
        }

        mysql_close($con);
    }
}
```

In this case your method (not a static function!) will be available, for example, test this code:

```
include_once("MainClass.php");

$MainClass = new MainClass();
$MainClass->filterUser("testuser");
```

Comment: change include_once to require_once in my sample code

Comment: Don't add warnings like that to answers by other people. More important never link to that terrible resource. You just made this answer utter crap @niklesh

Comment: @softwarrior may I ask what is the ("testuser"); for?

Comment: @YellowSubmarine it's just for the test, because your method expects one parameter

Comment: @YellowSubmarine do you have another error or error the same as before after you made changes for include_once statement?

Comment: tried using require_once and tried ("testuser") and my original ($username) but it still shows the same error

Comment: @YellowSubmarine you have to publish your MainClass.php code. As for me - it should work if included correctly. You can check, if your class loaded correctly by class_exists() call (http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php), check if your method exists by method_exists() call (http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107615/discussion-between-softwarrior-and-yellowsubmarine).